# How to incorporate selecting by date when comparing the same attributes?

Tags: sql, oracle

If the record has a ‘D’ type from a operation = ‘177’ then it must have the following:
A subsequent operation other than 097 and 190, with a the following types  (‘Y’,’S’,’T’).

The table has a many to 1 relationship and looks like this:

```
ID  |   operation  |  type   |   date  
1   |   177        |   D     |   09/12/12
1   |   136        |   S     |   03/12/15
2   |   177        |   D     |   04/15/13
2   |   190        |   Y     |   05/05/14
3   |   177        |   A     |   09/21/12
3   |   012        |   D     |   08/12/16
4   |   177        |   D     |   09/13/15
4   |   122        |   T     |   11/11/11
```

In the above table, the only IDs we'd want returned are 1 (date is more recent) and 3 (operation 177 is not type D).  We wouldn't want 2, because we exclude operation 190, and we wouldn't want 4, because operation 122 date is before operation 177.

So far, I've only been able to get to:

```
Select * 
from mytable
Where (operation = ‘177’ and type = ‘D’) 
  and ((operation not in (‘097’,’190’) and type in (‘Y’,’S’,’T’));
```

My question is, how do I select for records where the date of ((operation not in (‘097’,’190’) and type in (‘Y’,’S’,’T’))  is more recent than the date of (operation = ‘177’ and type = ‘D’)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying, here's my revised proposal. Basically, join to the same table on `id` and write a suitable where clause. I've chosen to bring back all fields. Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64b90/16) of this working

```
  select
  a.id
, a.operation
, a.type
, a.d
, b.operation
, b.type
, b.d
from mytable  a
inner join mytable  b on a.id=b.id 
WHERE (a.operation ='177' and a.type='D')
  and b.type in ('Y','S','T')
  and a.d<b.d;
```

Comment: Type D is a suggestion to delete the record.  
what happened was employee (operator) 177 did a poor job w/ their delete suggestions.
As such, we want to find all records where they suggested to delete, but another operator suggested 
to do something else to that record (at a later date than the D type took place)

Comment: I attempted to run the query, but nothing was returned; any ideas?

Comment: @user7002207 , based on the additional information I've revised my proposed answer. Does this produce the desired result?